# Do I need to include "for you" here, or is it implied?

Tags: ellipsis

> By default, few game profiles are already installed **to quickly get up and running**.

Is this correct use? Or should I say "**for you** to quickly get up and running"?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Unfortunately, proofreading is out of scope for us. If you have a specific area of concern in this sentence, please point that out and ask a question that is more specific to that concern.

Comment: I have confusion at "to quickly get up and running". Is this correct use?

Comment: Or should I say "for you to quickly get up and running" ?

Comment: The "quickly get up and running" is for anyone, it's not just for *you*, also sine the "you" person is reading the instructions, it is safe to assume it is implied.

Answer (score -1):

""By default, few game profiles are already installed to quickly get up and running.

In any event, it is not "you" that gets up and running, it's the computer!